# How to find the equation of the side and the diagonal of a square?

Tags: geometry

**Question:**

> The three vertices of a square $ABCD$ are $A(3,2), B(6,−2)$, and $C(2,−5)$. Find the equation of the side $CD$ and the equation of the diagonal $BD$.

**My attempt:**

- Equation of side $CD$: $4x+3y+7=0$
- Equation of diagonal $BD$: ??

Is my answer for the equation of the side $CD$ correct? I am not able to solve for the equation of the diagonal $BD$. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

---

**slope of side $CD$:**
$m_{CD}=m_{AB}=\dfrac{(−2−2)}{(6−3)}=\dfrac{-4}{3}=-1.33$ $\left[\because AB \parallel CD\right]$

**equation of side $CD$:**
$$y - y_1 = m(x - x_1) point slope form$$
$\Rightarrow y+5=\dfrac{−4}{3}(x−2) \Rightarrow 4x+3y+7=0$

But I am not sure how to solve for the equation of the diagonal $BD$.

I have constructed the square in GeoGebra and I found that the coordinates of $D$ are $(-1,-1)$ and the slope of $BD$ is $\dfrac{-1}{7}=-0.14$.
[image]

But I am not able to solve for the equation of the same. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you don't know the slope of the line $BD$ but you do know the two points it passes through, you can use the point-point form for the equation of the line. Alternatively, since you know two points on the line, you can calculate the slope from them and then use the point-slope form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slope of CD is equal to slope of AB and is equal to $(-2-2)/(6-3)=-4/3$, therefore equation of CD is $y=y_C-\frac{4}{3}(x-x_C)=-5-\frac{4}{3}(x-2)=-\frac{4}{3}x-\frac{7}{3}$. Multiplying by 3 to avoid fractions and moving all terms to left-hand side gives $4x+3y+7=0$.

Center of square is middle of AC and middle of BD.

Middle of AC is $(\frac{x_A+x_C}{2},\frac{y_A+y_C}{2})=(2.5,-1.5)$

Let D is $(x,y)$, then middle of BD is $(\frac{x_B+x_D}{2},\frac{y_B+y_D}{2})=(x/2+3,y/2-1)$

$2.5=x/2+3\Rightarrow x=-1$

$-1.5=y/2-1\Rightarrow y=-1$

So, D is $(-1,-1)$

Slope of BD is $(y_D-y_B)/(x_D-x_B)=(-1+2)/(-1-6)=-1/7$

Equation of BD is $y=y_B-\frac{1}{7}(x-x_B)=-2-\frac{1}{7}(x-6)=-\frac{1}{7}x-\frac{8}{7}$

Multiplying by 7 to avoid fractions and moving all terms to left-hand side gives $x+7y+8=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It is very well known that the equation of the linear function is
$y=kx+b$, therefore, we have to determine the equation of $BD$ from the next system:
$$
\begin{cases}
-1=-1*k+b,\\
-2=6*k+b.
\end{cases}
$$
Performing that system we get that $b=\frac{-8}{7}$, but $k=(b+1)$, therefore, $k=\frac{-1}{7}$.

$BD$ has the next equation: $y=-\frac{1}{7}*x-\frac{8}{7}$.

Good luck!